# Is $B(w_1 w_2)B = (Bw_1B)(Bw_2B)$?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let $B$ be a Borel subgroup of $GL_n$ and $W$ the Weyl group of $GL_n$. Let $w_1, w_2 \in W$. Is $B(w_1 w_2)B = (Bw_1B)(Bw_2B)$? If this is true. How to prove it? Thank you very much.

Edit: If $l(w_1 w_2) = l(w_1) + l(w_2)$, is $B(w_1 w_2)B = (Bw_1B)(Bw_2B)$?

Comment: Do you mean $w_1$ and $w_2$ to be elements of $N_G(T)$ (since the Weyl group is not a subgroup of $G$)?

Comment: The easiest counterexample is with $n=2$ to select $w_i=n_iT, i=1,2$ where $n_1,n_2$ are both non-diagonal monomial matrices (representing the non-identity element of $W$). Then $n_1n_2$ is diagonal, so $B(n_1n_2)B=B$. But $(Bn_1B)(Bn_2B)$ is much bigger - the whole group IIRC.

Comment: What you are looking at is an archetypal [Tits system](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Tits_system). Read a bit about those to get an idea of what's going on.